# Django display a complex formset

Tags: django, formset

I'm trying to display a complex modelForm formset in a table. My models are something like this:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    # whatever
    pass

class Child(models.Model):
    CHOICES1 = (1,2,3)
    CHOICES2 = (1,2)
    CHOICES3 = (1,2,3,4)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent')
    one = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES1)
    two = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES2)
    three = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES3)
    var = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

... each object in Parent has many Children - in this case 20. One instance for each combination of CHOICES1, CHOICES2, and CHOICES3. I want to have a form to edit the field `var` on each Child for a given Parent. So my form looks like this:

```
class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        hidden = ('parent', 'one', 'two', 'three') 
        # i.e. only var is the only visible form field.

children_formset = modelformset_factory(Child, form=ChildForm)
```

I can loop over this and make a nice table with 1 column and 20 rows, but how do I make a square of this e.g. Where "1" and "2" are just labels, but var1.1.1 ... var3.3.3 are the `var` formfields from the formset, with one table cell per form in formset.

```
|CHOICE1 | CHOICE2  | CHOICE3.1   | CHOICE3.2  | CHOICE3.3   
|=========================================================
|   1    |     1    |  var1.1.1   |  var1.1.2  | var1.1.3
|   1    |     2    |  var1.2.1   |  var1.2.2  | var1.2.3 
|   2    |     1    |  var2.1.1   |  var2.1.2  | var2.1.3
|   2    |     2    |  var2.2.1   |  var2.2.2  | var2.2.3
|   3    |     1    |  var3.1.1   |  var3.1.2  | var3.1.3
|   3    |     2    |  var3.2.1   |  var3.2.2  | var3.3.3
```

(Forgive the ASCII).

I could loop over these and insert a  after every 3rd cell. BUT I really don't want the inputs to get mixed up (i.e. what happens on a form submit with errors - how do I ensure the correct ordering of forms in my formset?)

I could hard-code it, but the number of choices is probably likely to vary as the project goes along.

So what's the best way to deal with this? One idea I had would be to avoid model forms and create another form with 20 fields called 1.1.1 to 3.3.3. and do it manually myself, but is there anything easier?

Comment: Have you looked at Formsets? They're typically used for one-to-many model relationships, but I think you could use them in this case, too. Formsets have a good flow for handling multiple, identical forms.